# MySQL query is not inserting data into the table

Tags: php

```
        $stmt= $mysqli->prepare("insert into book_project.personal_details(name,email,cc_num,address,city,zipcode) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        var_dump($_SESSION);

        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['cc_num'],$_SESSION['address'],$_SESSION['city'],$_SESSION['zipcode']);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();
}
```

I have a id column as primary key have not included it. id auto increments. I do not know to find errors. I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you check for any errors later on in the code? if not, do so! http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 2):

You have 7 parameters here:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['cc_num'],$_SESSION['address'],$_SESSION['city'],$_SESSION['zipcode']);
```

But there are only 6 placeholders in the SQL query:

```
$stmt= $mysqli->prepare("insert into book_project.personal_details(name,email,cc_num,address,city,zipcode) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: where are there 7 params! I see 6 everywhere!

Comment: 'ssssss' is the first (or seventh) which shouldn't be there.. (@CodeBird)

Comment: yeah `bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )` the first `ssssss` is the types ----> http://jp.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php